# Youtube Upload using javascript in Developers Account

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api, video-upload

We're uploading videos on youtube, but we're facing issues when page loads on client side, it asks for signin to users, we need them to upload video in our account

Usage
**Javascript Api**
Referred :-https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

How can we upload without node server & with auto signin in our account using **javscript(frontend)**